# Objective C - IB - Vertically centering 3 multiline UILabels

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I have 3 UILabels stacked on top of each other like so:

[image]

The top label can be 2 lines, but isn't all of the time. I'm trying to vertically center all 3 labels between the top and bottom lines in picture. I'm just not sure how to go about doing it. I've tried setting the space between them equal and give ≥ margins on the top and bottom but it doesn't seem to work.

Trying to do this without code, all in the interface builder if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try putting the three labels inside a `UIView`, and then assigning that `UIView` to align to the center of the `UIImageView`.

You can easily do this by selecting all three UILabels, and going to `Editor->Embed In->UIView`. Select the new view and *Shift Click* on the image and select `Editor->Align->Vertical Centers`

Answer (score 0):

Forget about using different labels for this, it's nightmare. Use `NSAttributedString` with one `UILabel` it'll automatically center the text.

```
NSString *name = @"John\nMultiline\nSmith"; // your multiline string
NSString *title = @"Salesguy"; // some more strings
NSString *phone = @"555-55-55";
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@", name, title, phone] attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17.0]}]; // construct the label with default parameters
[attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17.0] range:[attributedString.string rangeOfString:name]]; // add bold selection to the name part
myLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```